# Merging erases details on top object

Tags: objects

Hi I have a problem where I go to merge two objects, one has incredibly small details and as such when I go to merge, the little edges vanish and I'm left with one solid block.

[image] Pic related is what I want the end result to be, this is before I merge the two.

Comment: if you modeled those tiny edges using modifiers ( you could add more detail on this), it could be needed to apply them first (thus, making real geometry).

Comment: I used the array modifier to get the amount that I have but I did apply it I believe. I just dragged an edge down on another to get the spikey shape

Comment: if you applied the array and that only created the repetition, it should join fine, leaving all the details... try uploading your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add the provided link, editing your question

Answer (score 1):

I'll add here an example:

starting from an array modifier creating similar details

[image]

you should apply it: pressing the "apply" button you get something  like this

[image]

then if you join with the underlying shape

[image]

details are still there

[image]